# How to start a flow in Corda

Tags: corda

I am exploring this cordapp example https://github.com/corda/corda-training-template.git

I have modified the code as per the solution template available in Github. Whenever I am starting the flow, I am getting error like (no constructor found, missing parameter state), please refer to the below screenshot. 
I have initiated this flow from node A so I am confused about what will be the constructor parameter. I have pasted the state code below.

[Flow issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvRtx.png)

**IOUState Constructor code**

```
@BelongsToContract(IOUContract.class)
public class IOUState implements ContractState, LinearState {

    public final Amount<Currency> amount;
    public final Party lender;
    public final Party borrower;
    public final Amount<Currency> paid;
    private final UniqueIdentifier linearId;

    // Private constructor used only for copying a State object
    @ConstructorForDeserialization
    private IOUState(Amount<Currency> amount, Party lender, Party borrower, Amount<Currency> paid, UniqueIdentifier linearId){
        this.amount = amount;
        this.lender = lender;
        this.borrower = borrower;
        this.paid = paid;
        this.linearId = linearId;
    }

    public IOUState(Amount<Currency> amount, Party lender, Party borrower) {
        this(amount, lender, borrower, new Amount<>(0, amount.getToken()), new UniqueIdentifier());
    }

    public Amount<Currency> getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public Party getLender() {
        return lender;
    }

    public Party getBorrower() {
        return borrower;
    }

    public Amount<Currency> getPaid() {
        return paid;
    }

    @Override
    public UniqueIdentifier getLinearId() {
        return linearId;
    }

    /**
     *  This method will return a list of the nodes which can "use" this state in a valid transaction. In this case, the
     *  lender or the borrower.
     */
    @Override
    public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants() {
        return ImmutableList.of(lender, borrower);
    }

    /**
     * Helper methods for when building transactions for settling and transferring IOUs.
     * - [pay] adds an amount to the paid property. It does no validation.
     * - [withNewLender] creates a copy of the current state with a newly specified lender. For use when transferring.
     * - [copy] creates a copy of the state using the internal copy constructor ensuring the LinearId is preserved.
     */
    public IOUState pay(Amount<Currency> amountToPay) {
        Amount<Currency> newAmountPaid = this.paid.plus(amountToPay);
        return new IOUState(amount, lender, borrower, newAmountPaid, linearId);
    }

    public IOUState withNewLender(Party newLender) {
        return new IOUState(amount, newLender, borrower, paid, linearId);
    }

    public IOUState copy(Amount<Currency> amount, Party lender, Party borrower, Amount<Currency> paid) {
        return new IOUState(amount, lender, borrower, paid, this.getLinearId());
    }

}
```

Comment: Please share the code of the **flow’s constructor**; the state’s code is irrelevant here.

Comment: 1. I am using the IOUState instance as Flow's constructor.

public static class InitiatorFlow extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
        private final IOUState state;
        public InitiatorFlow(IOUState state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

2. I am running the below command to initiate the flow.

flow start IOUIssueFlow$InitiatorFlow IOUState: {amount: 500, lender: ParticipantA, borrower: ParticipantC}

Comment: `amount: 500` is wrong; see explanation in my answer.

Comment: I have changed the IssueFlow constructor as per your suggestion and it's working now perfectly. I have instantiated the IOUState object inside the call method.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I assume that one of the input parameters in your flow's constructor is a class (`Amount<Currency>`), so you have to pass an instance of that class when you start the flow in the node's shell.
2. See [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/shell.html#creating-an-instance-of-a-class) how to create an instance of a class in the node's shell.
3. The problem in your code is that you're using `Amount<Currency>`; meaning to construct an instance, you'd have to do something like this:

```java
Amount<Currency> usdAmount = new Amount(100, Currency.getInstance("USD"));
```

4. We have to use `Currency.getInstance()`, because `Currency` doesn't have a `public` constructor. From `Currency` code:

```java
/**
 * Constructs a <code>Currency</code> instance. The constructor is private
 * so that we can insure that there's never more than one instance for a
 * given currency.
 */
private Currency(String currencyCode, int defaultFractionDigits, int numericCode) {
    this.currencyCode = currencyCode;
    this.defaultFractionDigits = defaultFractionDigits;
    this.numericCode = numericCode;
}
```

5. The node shell doesn't allow calling functions (i.e. `Currency.getInstance()`).
6. So in order for your flow to work, you have to modify its constructor and make it accept only primitive parameters as opposed to taking classes as well; then inside the constructor you can create an instance of the `Amount` class. It would look like this:

```java
// Class attributes.
private Amount<Currency> iouAmount;
private Party otherParty;

// Constructor.
public Initiator(String currencyCode, long quantity, Party otherParty) {
    this.iouAmount = new Amount(quantity, Currency.getInstance(currencyCode));
    this.otherParty = otherParty;
}
```

Now inside the node's shell:

```
flow start IOUIssueFlow$Initiator currencyCode: USD, quantity: 100, otherParty: PartyB
```

7. Please note that you're using `Amount`, so `quantity` must be of type `long`. See [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/45b43f116d894d0fd9e00eba3736c727ebe02b51/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/contracts/Amount.kt#L42).